# How to change the civil war factions' relationships?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Every time I go through the quest Season Unending, I think I have chosen the neutral route (I even followed a walkthrough on one occasion where the outcome was score 3-3), but after I finish the main quest, kill Alduin, and start clearing bandits from forts and so on, some are taken over by Imperials and I have to start making large detours in order not to kill them. I don’t want to play the Civil War questline, I just want both factions to treat me as neutral so I can pass through their forts and camps.

I have never killed a member of either faction. I have no civil war mods in my game. I don’t want to play the civil war.
Before Season Unending I can walk into any camps without any problems, but after Season Unending I am called 'Unblooded' by some of the Stormcloaks, and if I approach an Imperial camp they draw their swords and say things like "you're trespassing, get away or else" or words to that effect.

I have been informed by other players that after Season Unending they can still walk through any civil war faction’s camp and forts, but I can’t.

I was hoping for a console command to set things to neutral again, even if that changes who owns which city.

Answer (score 3):

After *Season Unending*, use the console commands `player.addfac 2BF9A 0` and `player.addfac 28849 0` to become neutral in regards to the Imperial Legion and Stormcloaks respectively.

---

Here are some gameplay tips for anyone who has not yet started *Season Unending*:

To assert remaining neutral during and after the quest **it is paramount that you introduce the negotiations with the dialogue option "*I have a message from the Greybeards*"**.
If this option is missing when talking to either Ulfric or Tullius about brokering the treaty, the [UESP](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Season_Unending#Notes) suggests the following potential solution:

> If you have not yet joined either the Imperial Legion or the Stormcloaks, and you have not talked to Ulfric and/or Tullius since Helgen, you will be forced to first talk to them about Helgen, at which point **they will suggest that you join their side of the conflict**. To proceed, simply finish and exit the first dialogue, then start a new discussion, at which point the option will appear.

User DrNewcenstein [points out in one of the Steam threads](https://steamcommunity.com/app/489830/discussions/0/1696045708638754233/#c1696045708642229522) that the only other option to request their presence at High Hrothgar is indeed to express your support for either faction:

> When you get to Season Unending and approach either Ulfric or Tullius first, you're locked into a dialog option that says "*I could have gone anywhere after Helgen, I came here to fight for <faction>*". **This essentially commits you to that faction.**

Answer (score -4):

On console the only way to do so is NOT doing the quest line otherwise i think you'll need to find a console command to reset that.